# A simple Vector in Java that produces some tricky output

Tags: java, vector

A very simple Vector in Java that produces the output that is somewhat difficult to follow. The code snippet is as show below.

```
package main;

import java.util.Vector;

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {        
        Vector<String> r = new Vector<String>();
        r.addElement("O");
        r.addElement("Y");
        r.insertElementAt("A",0);
        r.addElement("B");
        r.addElement("F");
        r.addElement("I");
        r.addElement("X");
        r.removeElement("F");
        r.insertElementAt("G",3);

        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

---

The above simple Java code produces the output that is different than it actually appears to be. The actual output the above code produces is surprisingly, **[A, O, Y, G, B, I, X]**. Actually, it contains 9 elements. The output however, contains only 7 elements. How?

Comment: Huh? You added 7 things, removed one, then added another. My arithmetic says that equals ... 7.

Comment: I'm lost, where are nine things? Am I being stupid?

Comment: @DaveNewton - No, I believe your arithmetic is also working as intended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you notice that one of them was `removeElement`?

Comment: ::sigh:: Fine. +1 for pointing out the obvious. Though it's almost like cheating :-p

Answer (score 0):

Actually you would have forget about the statement removeElement("F"). Since it is called it was removed and remaining elements alone shown. If you comment this line and try again, your expected result will come. Cheers up!!!